# Access static property from variable referenced to a class

Tags: typescript

I have a need to dynamically select a prototype class for an object and access to a static property within the reference. But looks like ts does not understand my type juggling.

```js
abstract class AbsClass {
  protected static alias?: string;
}

class Dodge extends AbsClass {
  protected static alias = "ddg";
}

class Derived extends AbsClass {
  protected static alias = "drv";
  getAlias(obj?: AbsClass) {
     const accessClass = (obj?.constructor ?? this.constructor) as AbsClass; 
     return accessClass.alias; // error compile there: alias is not accessible in AbsClass (did you mean to access the static member?)
    // but 'alias' is accessible as expression `this.constructor.alias` in debugger
  }
}

const der = new Derived();
console.log(der.getAlias());
```

Note that `alias` is accessible as expression `this.constructor.alias` in debugger.

Is it possible to prepare like `accessClass.alias` expression avoiding access property via class name directly?

ps. Please tolerate my example because it is only a template for what i'm trying to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alias` is a static field so it does not exist on type `AbsClass` since it is a type of an object produced by the class constructor.

Changing `AbsClass` to `typeof AbsClass` removes the error:

```js
class Derived extends AbsClass {
  protected static alias = "drv";

  getAlias(obj?: typeof AbsClass) { // <- Type changed here
    const accessClass = (obj?.constructor ?? this.constructor) as typeof AbsClass; // <- and here
    return accessClass.alias;
  }
}
```

[Playground with full example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgguAwq9CA3gFAIIAOUA9hAKby0AmCkwEAlrAsMu2gPwAuFtHYA7AOYBuYgF9ixFGgwARKowm0EtAB50xjDNjB5lRUhWp0GzVhy48+GALwIARIw1uZ8xflW0UOwAbkzaerQGRrj+5mSUNPR0thBsnNy8aAiuHlDB3haaEJiZYAAUVCAAVkIIEACe5LRUAGZYMcoAlHFkZLBUYpDcsLC06KYErhXV-AB0-YPQAK7wVFAI-Px1ABbsYPMDkFArEGvdWQ1Nre0m-lIIFr1QtBBLUGLDo+P+s45oMmR5L4FkNGIFsggxLQAO4IFSBEJMMqdGQgqjIWizZBUCRlMFQWZFEpOZEo4hAA)

[Link to the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes) where the difference between the static and instance sides of classes is described in details.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it does not work. Compiler tells the same error.

Comment: @ThomasAnderson please find a link to a playground with a full example

Comment: Wonderful. That's what i need.